# Recovering Leads from Campaign Members Section in a Campaign

Tags: leads, campaign, delete

While going through the campaign members section of a campaign, I accidentally deleted some records. They do not appear in my recycle bin. How/Where do I go to recover them?

Comment: Contact support. They probably can't help you, but that's your only chance if they're already gone from the `Recycle Bin`.

Answer (score -1):

When you remove Campaign members, they don't show up in the recycle bin because you don't actually delete anything. The contacts or leads are still there, so you may be able to recreate the list of Campaign members based on the same criteria for selection as you did when you selected those members in the first place.

The good news is when you recreate the members list, no duplicates are added.

Comment: well, sort of, you are technically deleting the junction record `CampaignMember` that relates a Campaign to a Lead (or Contact)

Comment: How would an external sync that matches the campaign member know it has been deleted then?